# PHP: DOMDocument cannot be found within a class

Tags: php, domdocument

I've got a very weird problem, I have a class named getResources where I want to scrape and extract every CSS location on a $url. Here it is:

```
class getResources {
    public function getCSSCount($sitename) {
        $count = '0';
        $file = file_get_contents($sitename);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($file);
        $domcss = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');
        foreach($domcss as $links) {
            if( strtolower($links->getAttribute('rel')) == "stylesheet" ) {
                $count++;
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

The problem is that DOMDocument cannot be found even though php-xml is installed and working as shown here:

```
root@robin [~]# php -i|grep DOM
DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
```

I've tested the function by removing it from it's class and parsing via the index.php file directly and it works fine. The problem is that DOMDocument cannot be found if it's within a class. Does anyone know how to fix something like this?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: It require libxml >= 2.6.0 (http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.requirements.php)

Comment: Do you have namespaces by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we had [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52647607/4271117). It could be the namespace issue. You can try this:

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having php7 and php5.6 installed on your machine, then simply installing php-xml will not work. the problem is that php-xml installs xml libraries for php7 and does not take care for php5 versions.

To use that, you need to run the following command on Ubuntu:
1. If you have php7 and php5.6 both installed: (i.e. the new ppa => ppa:ondrej/php), then use the following command,

> sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml php5.6-xmlrpc

2. If you only have php5 installed

> sudo apt-get install php5-xml php5-xmlrpc