# Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting\DOMDocument' not found

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, google-ads-api

I have php-xml installed and it runs fine with other php files using the following code to display xml on a web site:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML(html_entity_decode($xml), LIBXML_NOXMLDECL);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

But it won't work in Google AdWords Report API. It obviously has something to do with the `namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting;` I am not familiar with PHP and wonder how to get this `DOMDocument` working inside the `Reporting` namespace. Thanks.

Comment: Add a slash before the class name: `$doc = new \DOMDocument();`  That will force it to not use the current namespace.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. This certainly solved the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a backslash `\` before the `DOMDocument` to load the class from the global namespace. Otherwise php searches for the DOMDocument class in your current namespace.

If you need more information about this, you may want to take a look at the [php documentation for global namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php):

```
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
```